# How to send request for PHP file_get_contents via web server

Tags: php

Since, YouTube is blocked on my ISP, I am trying to get the contents of a YouTube video page using **file_get_contents** but I get the same error as I am trying to open YouTube in my browser like, Website Blocked.

It means, the request to YouTube website is being sent from my ISP and not from the webserver where I am hosting my web page. So How do I send the request via Web Server?

Comment: which isp is blocking YouTube O_o !?

Comment: You need a full proxy script, which replaces all the links on the page to go through your server, otherwise it makes no sense. The easiest way - buy VPN service and use it to bypass the filter. Or, if you have ssh access to the server - you can use the tunnel connection to it (almost the same as VPN)

Comment: @andrew: I'm in Pakistan, and PTCL here is blocking YT.

Comment: @Cheery: well, i thought like we can download any file on any server to using PHP, we can also get the source code. can't we?

Comment: @JunaidRehman you can, if there are no redirects and no special setup of the remote server as `file_get_contents` does not send full http headers. Even if you get the source, css/js/images will not load, as they either have a absolute URL or will try to load from your server. Also it depends on how access if blocked - by the keyword in get request, for example.. in this very broad case if request to your server has it - it will be also blocked.

Comment: Is this something that pre-existing proxy software won't fix, for example PHProxy?

Comment: If you're using `file_get_contents` then the server will be relaying the content, though not effectively as @Cheery states. I imagine the site is blocked by locale based on ip range, so if the server is also in Pakistan it too may be blocked

Comment: @Cheery I am not trying to load the images and other contents, just the source code of the page, just like we open a web page, right click, and view source code..

Comment: @andrew well luckily the server isn't in Pakistan.

Comment: @JunaidRehman access can be blocked on another level, like it is done in many countries. Also youtube can block access to it based on country.

Comment: @Nerixel Thanks, i am gonna give it a try